# Synonymize [twitter] and [twitter-rest-api]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[twitter-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-api) is already a synonym of [twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter) — I see no reason [twitter-rest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-rest-api) should be any different.